# CentOS 6.5 Iptables conntrack module

Tags: centos, iptables, centos6.5, conntrack

I have a VPS server on which CentOS 6.5 x64 is installed. Kernel version from `uname` command is **2.6.18-028stab107**.

When I want to use iptables rate limiting like in the following command, I got the error message below.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

I think required conntrack modules are not installed on system, lsmod command output is empty.

```
[root@myserver ~]# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
```

I try to load modules like below, and got the errors.

```
[root@myserver ~]# modprobe ip_conntrack
FATAL: Module ip_conntrack not found.
[root@myserver ~]# modprobe nf_conntrack
FATAL: Module nf_conntrack not found.
```

Finally, I think, I have to install state and conntrack modules, but cant install because yum search result does not include required packages.

```
[root@myserver ~]# yum search conntrack
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                                                                                          | 5.2 kB     00:00     
 * base: sg2plmirror01.shr.prod.sin2.secureserver.net
 * epel: kartolo.sby.datautama.net.id
 * extras: sg2plmirror01.shr.prod.sin2.secureserver.net
base                                                                                                   | 3.7 kB     00:00     
base/primary_db                                                                                        | 4.4 MB     00:00     
epel                                                                                                   | 4.4 kB     00:00     
epel/primary_db                                                                                        | 6.1 MB     00:02     
extras                                                                                                 | 3.4 kB     00:00     
extras/primary_db                                                                                      |  18 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates/primary_db                                                                                     | 3.1 MB     00:02     
=================================================== N/S Matched: conntrack ===================================================
libnetfilter_conntrack.i686 : Netfilter conntrack userspace library
libnetfilter_conntrack.x86_64 : Netfilter conntrack userspace library
libnetfilter_conntrack-devel.i686 : Netfilter conntrack userspace library
libnetfilter_conntrack-devel.x86_64 : Netfilter conntrack userspace library

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

How can install these modules and use my iptables commands given at the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on a VPS, a container running on a Linux box and isolated from the host system. So you can't control the host's kernel.